# MKMapView seems to be nil?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gps, mapkit

I am new to Xcode and Swift and I am trying to simply make a map that shows the users current location and updates it. I have this so far:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var mapp = MKMapView.self

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
        {
            self.locationManager.delegate = self
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.map.showsUserLocation = true
        }
        else
        {
            print("Location services are not enabled")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func loadView() {
        //let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 36.2108, longitude: -81.6774, zoom: 15.0)
        //let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        //mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        //view = mapView
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.002, longitudeDelta: 0.002))
        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
    {
        print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

I have made a MapView in the storyboard and CTRL dragged it to the file (thus the @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!). However, when I plug my phone in and simulate the app it gives me a "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" and after some print statements i found that it happened whenever I referenced the map variable. Why is this? Thanks!

Comment: have you checked your app's capabilities tab? maps should be on there (and it's off by default).

Comment: Remove the `loadView` method. That's used only when you are programmatically creating views. When using storyboards (or NIBs), you put your configuration code in `viewDidLoad`, not `loadView`.

Comment: @Rob is right.  Remove `loadView` and it should work.

Comment: Wow thank you Rob for the quick answer. It worked! woohoo! It zoomed to my current location, however there is no blue dot indicating exactly where i am? How would i go about getting that? thanks!

Comment: Woops, it took a little while to load, but it did finally show up! Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments of the original post, Rob answered the question:

"
Remove the loadView method. That's used only when you are programmatically creating views. When using storyboards (or NIBs), you put your configuration code in viewDidLoad, not loadView. – Rob"

thank you Rob